# NullPointerException while working with GestureDetector

Tags: android, android-animation, gesture

Below is the code of loading frameanimation for two different images on the occurrence of different events.First event is while the activity start.Others are the `onTouch()` where i making use of `GestureDetector` for the `onDown()` and `onScroll()` The problem is that i get `NullPointerException` while its in the `OnScroll()`.I found that it is not getting the Y coordinates what can be the issue.

```
package com.example.animationtry;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    ImageView img,img1;
    AnimationDrawable animation;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        img.post(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                img.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.frameanimation);
                AnimationDrawable frameAnimation =  (AnimationDrawable) img .getBackground();
                frameAnimation.setVisible(false, true);
                frameAnimation.start();
            }
        });
        img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
            {
                String img="img";
                gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector(img));
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) 
                {
                    return true;
                }   
                return false;
            }
        });

        img1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
        img.post(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                img1.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.frameanimation);
                AnimationDrawable frameAnimation =  (AnimationDrawable) img1.getBackground();
                frameAnimation.setVisible(false, true);
                frameAnimation.start();
            }
        });
        img1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
            {
                String img1="img1";
                gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector(img1));
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) 
                {
                    return true;
                }   
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener
    {
        private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 40;
        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 30;
        String viewname;
        public MyGestureDetector(String view)
        {
            viewname=view;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,float velocityY) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) 
        {
            Log.i("View Name",viewname);
            if(viewname.equalsIgnoreCase("img"))
            {
                img.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.clickanimation);
                animation = (AnimationDrawable)img.getBackground();
                animation.setVisible(false, true);
                animation.start();
            }
            else if(viewname.equalsIgnoreCase("img1"))
            {
                img1.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.clickanimation);
                animation = (AnimationDrawable)img1.getBackground();
                animation.setVisible(false, true);
                animation.start();
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,float distanceX, float distanceY) 
        {
            Log.i("y1",Float.toString(e1.getY()));
            Log.i("y2",Float.toString(e2.getY()));
            Log.i("Drag View Name",viewname);
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH && Math.abs(distanceY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) 
            {
                if(viewname.equalsIgnoreCase("img"))
                {
                    img.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.draganimaton);
                    animation = (AnimationDrawable)img.getBackground();
                    animation.setVisible(false, true);
                    animation.start();
                }
                else if(viewname.equalsIgnoreCase("img1"))
                {
                    img1.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.draganimaton);
                    animation = (AnimationDrawable)img1.getBackground();
                    animation.setVisible(false, true);
                    animation.start();
                }
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

and below is the logcat:

```
01-12 06:12:22.637: E/AndroidRuntime(1062): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 06:12:22.637: E/AndroidRuntime(1062): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-12 06:12:22.637: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at com.example.animationtry.MainActivity$MyGestureDetector.onScroll(MainActivity.java:117)
01-12 06:12:22.637: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:541)
01-12 06:12:22.637: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at com.example.animationtry.MainActivity$4.onTouch(MainActivity.java:69)
01-12 06:12:22.637: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3881)
01-12 06:12:22.637: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
01-12 06:12:22.637: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
01-12 06:12:22.637: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
01-12 06:12:22.637: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
01-12 06:12:22.637: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1691)
01-12 06:12:22.637: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1125)
01-12 06:12:22.637: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
01-12 06:12:22.637: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1675)
01-12 06:12:22.637: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2194)
01-12 06:12:22.637: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1878)
01-12 06:12:22.637: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-12 06:12:22.637: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-12 06:12:22.637: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-12 06:12:22.637: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 06:12:22.637: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-12 06:12:22.637: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-12 06:12:22.637: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-12 06:12:22.637: E/AndroidRuntime(1062):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: oh got what u want to say... u mean return true in the onTouch() right. i did that but again its giving me the same error..

Comment: @sankettt : problem is because event is null yes you are right you are retuning true . then try to override onTouchEvent method of  SimpleOnGestureListener

Comment: its working fine with the `onDown()` event properly and its not working for `onScroll()` and from logcat i see that it is not getting the value of X and Y. this problem came only when i changed the constructor,i have to make the create constructor because i as i have more than 1 image i need the id of each image so that i can know which image to animate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the problem `e1.getY()` returning null value for the `onScroll()` so i removed that checking part and just checked `SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH` with the `distanceY` of the `onScroll()` and now its working perfectly..

```
package com.example.animationtry;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    ImageView img,img1;
    AnimationDrawable animation;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 40;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 30;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        img.post(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                img.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.frameanimation);
                AnimationDrawable frameAnimation =  (AnimationDrawable) img .getBackground();
                frameAnimation.setVisible(false, true);
                frameAnimation.start();
            }
        });
        img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
            {
                String img="img";
                gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector(img));
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) 
                {
                    return true;
                }   
                return false;
            }
        });

        img1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
        img.post(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                img1.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.frameanimation);
                AnimationDrawable frameAnimation =  (AnimationDrawable) img1.getBackground();
                frameAnimation.setVisible(false, true);
                frameAnimation.start();
            }
        });
        img1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
            {
                String img1="img1";
                gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector(img1));
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) 
                {
                    return true;
                }   
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener
    {
        String viewname;
        public MyGestureDetector(String view)
        {
            viewname=view;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,float velocityY) 
        {

            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) 
        {
            Log.i("View Name",viewname);
            if(viewname.equalsIgnoreCase("img"))
            {
                img.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.clickanimation);
                animation = (AnimationDrawable)img.getBackground();
                animation.setVisible(false, true);
                animation.start();
            }
            else if(viewname.equalsIgnoreCase("img1"))
            {
                img1.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.clickanimation);
                animation = (AnimationDrawable)img1.getBackground();
                animation.setVisible(false, true);
                animation.start();
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,float distanceX, float distanceY) 
        {           
            Log.i("Drag View Name",viewname);
            if (Math.abs(distanceY)>SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) 
            {
                Log.i("inside","drag");
                if(viewname.equalsIgnoreCase("img"))
                {
                    img.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.draganimaton);
                    animation = (AnimationDrawable)img.getBackground();
                    animation.setVisible(false, true);
                    animation.start();
                }
                else if(viewname.equalsIgnoreCase("img1"))
                {
                    img1.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.draganimaton);
                    animation = (AnimationDrawable)img1.getBackground();
                    animation.setVisible(false, true);
                    animation.start();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case distance not coming more than +-3. I am using an ListView and handling gesture on it's parent view.